# Email a file from iphone apps documents folder

Tags: iphone

I have managed to get in app email working in my app but am having trouble emailing an attachment. I am trying to email the core data .sqlite file. the email sends fine but when i recieve it there is no attachment. I have tried making a copy of the file and emailing that but still no good.

```
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/data.sqlite",documentPath];
NSString *Newpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/newData.sqlite",documentPath];
NSURL *theFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:Newpath];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:path toPath:Newpath error:nil];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: theFileUrl];

NSLog(@"%@",documentPath);
NSLog(@"%@",path);



[controller setSubject:@"Backup"];
[controller addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:@"data.sqlite"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"testing." isHTML:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where do you initially put your data.sqlite file... in resources or directly documents(manually)?..... please check whether there exist data.sqlite in documents or not...

Comment: Set a breakpoint after you set your data to see if it really got set. I compared your email attachment code to my own working code and it looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method `dataWithContentsOfFile`: rather than `dataWithContentsOfURL` for creating `data`. because it may need `file:///` protocol service.
Thanks,